# Remap tmux prefix shortcut of control b

Tags: tmux, remapping

I tried to remap `tmux` prefix shortcut from control b to control / by

```
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-/
bind-key C-/ send-prefix
```

but not fulfill the expectation, how is the correct way to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man tmux`:

> When specifying keys, most represent themselves (for example ‘A’ to
> ‘Z’). Ctrl keys may be prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘^’, and Alt (meta) with
> ‘M-’.
>
> In addition, the following special key names are accepted:
>
> Up, Down, Left, Right, BSpace, BTab, DC (Delete), End, Enter, Escape,
> F1 to F20, Home, IC (Insert), NPage/PageDown/PgDn, PPage/PageUp/PgUp, Space, and Tab. Note that to bind the ‘"’ or ‘'’ keys, quotation marks are necessary [...]

As you can see, a number of special keys are allowed, but `/` isn't one of them. So it's simply a case of that particular key not being bindable in `tmux`.

Your configuration is correct, so if you wanted to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> the prefix key, this would work:

```
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-x
bind-key C-x send-prefix
```

`tmux` also has an advanced feature called "user-keys", where custom escape sequences can be defined and bound, but I'm not sure it will help in this case, since `/` isn't an escape sequence.